# Karate UI: How to read external file (json) as test data and pass value in textbox

Tags: karate

Below is my feature file:

```
Feature: Check test Data

Background: 
* configure driver = {type: 'chrome'}
* def testData = read('classpath:src/test/resources/testdata/testfile.json')

Scenario: Verify test data
Given driver 'somevalid-url'
* input('#usernameTextField','testData.TC_001.username')
* input('#passwordTextField','testData.TC_001.password')
```

Here, to enter text I am doing 'testData.TC_001.username' but it doesn't work.

please find attached json:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, what does "it doesn't work" mean? Can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the quotes:

```
* input('#usernameTextField', testData.TC_001.username)
```

Experiment by hardcoding JSON in your test first:

```
* def testData = { TC_001: { username: 'foo' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"testData.testData.TC_001.username"` because you have created `"testData"` object in background step that you have to use to access the data from json.